# Type mismatch error in F#

Tags: function, f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

The script below should compute the first prime factor of a number. however, it throws an error on line 10, char 28 that

```
 ~vs7F27.fsx(10,28): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
 unit list    
 but given a
 int64 list    
 The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int64'
```

My code is below. Why does it want a unit as the type here? How do I change my code to allow for an int64?

```
let makeList x  = [2L..(x-1L)]
let divides x y = x%y = 0L
let isprime n =
    let rec check i =
        i > n/2L || (n % i <> 0L && check (i + 1L))
    check 2L
let findFirstPrimeFactor x = 
    let rec find y list = 
        if divides y (list |> List.head) &&  list |> List.head |> isprime 
            then List.head(list)
        if list |> List.length <> 1 then 1L
        else find y (list |> List.tail)
    find x (makeList x)

findFirstPrimeFactor 7L
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code indentation is misleading. It should be more like

```
let findFirstPrimeFactor x = 
    let rec find y list = 
        if divides y (list |> List.head) &&  list |> List.head |> isprime 
            then List.head(list)
                 if list |> List.length <> 1 then 1L
        else find y (list |> List.tail)
    find x (makeList x)
```

Which is why you're getting an error - `List.head(list)` is not last statement in that group, so it shouldn't return anything.

Change second `if` to `elif` to make it work:

```
let findFirstPrimeFactor x = 
    let rec find y list = 
        if divides y (list |> List.head) &&  list |> List.head |> isprime 
            then List.head(list)
        elif list |> List.length <> 1 then 1L
        else find y (list |> List.tail)
    find x (makeList x)
```